# Is there eny more efficient (and less tedious) way to do this?

Tags: java

For homework, I have to create my own method based on Character.isJavaIdentifierStart. 
It should consider only the characters ‘a’ through ‘z’ (lower and upper case), ‘$’, and ‘_’ to be valid. It returns a boolean value. Am I missing a simpler way to do this?

```
public static boolean myIsJavaIdentifierStart(char ch) {
    if (ch == '$' || ch == '_') {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        switch (ch) {
            case 'a':return true;
            case 'b':return true;
            case 'c':return true;
            case 'd':return true;
            case 'e':return true;
            case 'f':return true;
            case 'g':return true;
            case 'h':return true;
            case 'i':return true;
            case 'j':return true;
            case 'k':return true;
            case 'l':return true;
            case 'm':return true;
            case 'n':return true;
            case 'o':return true;
            case 'p':return true;
            case 'q':return true;
            case 'r':return true;
            case 's':return true;
            case 't':return true;
            case 'u':return true;
            case 'v':return true;
            case 'w':return true;
            case 'x':return true;
            case 'y':return true;
            case 'z':return true;
            case 'A':return true;
            case 'B':return true;
            case 'C':return true;
            case 'D':return true;
            case 'E':return true;
            case 'F':return true;
            case 'G':return true;
            case 'H':return true;
            case 'I':return true;
            case 'J':return true;
            case 'K':return true;
            case 'L':return true;
            case 'M':return true;
            case 'N':return true;
            case 'O':return true;
            case 'P':return true;
            case 'Q':return true;
            case 'R':return true;
            case 'S':return true;
            case 'T':return true;
            case 'U':return true;
            case 'V':return true;
            case 'W':return true;
            case 'X':return true;
            case 'Y':return true;
            case 'Z':return true;
            default: return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you ever considered the fact that a `char` in java is just an `int` in disguise?

Comment: `if ('a' <= ch && ch <= 'z')`

Comment: `else if (Character.isLetter(ch)) return true; else return false;`

Comment: @TNT `return (Character.isLetter(ch));`?

Comment: The if statements @Mysticial and @TNT provided are better, but in a `switch` execution falls through each `case` so you can do: `switch(ch){ case 'a': case 'A': case 'b': /*...*/ return true; default: return false; }`

Comment: The other very popular option in practice (although not necessarily what your tutor wants to see in this assignemnt) is [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: @Jefffrey OP says to also include `$` and `_`, though.

Comment: why do you make a separate `if` statement for `$` and `_`?

Comment: That was before I thought through how I could do the rest of the characters.

Comment: @Nishant There's a good lesson in this: once you finished your code, read it again with a critical eye. Often we jump into solutions that make sense at the time of writing, but once you're finished and take a step back, suddenly they seem awkward. Also don't be afraid to throw code away and starting from scratch if a solution feels tedious. You won't always be able to afford this but when you can, go for it.

Comment: A Java identifier can begin with a currency character. There are many different currency characters.

Comment: @TomBlodget the instructions for my assignment said that we only needed to check for freedom money.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are many other ways of doing this, but perhaps one of the simplest ones would be to expand upon something that you already have at the top of your method:

```
return ch == '$'
    || ch == '_'
    || (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
    || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z');
```

You need to note a couple of things to see why this works:

- You are returning a `boolean`, so any Boolean expression can be used directly, without an `if` statement
- Code points of letters `A`..`Z` and `a`..`z` in UNICODE are *consecutive*, enabling you to check for membership in `[A..Z]` or `[a..z]` intervals with a pair of `>=` and `<=` checks.

Answer (score 2):

There are certainly more efficient ways of doing this. 
1. characters 'a' to 'z' in standards such as Unicode and ASCII are consecutive integers. Therefore, instead of checking each individually, you can do if(ch >0 'a' && ch <= 'z').
Additionally, you can try using : return (Character.isLetter(ch));

See the following references:
- a list of all java character functions:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html

- ASCII table of character values:
  http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >='A' && ch <= 'Z'))
    return true;
```

Or if you want to convert it to a String/Character, you can use toLower:

```
Character lower = Character.toLowerCase(ch);
if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
    return true;
```